# How can I split a string into 4 variables using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I wan to split this string into 4 variables . 
"Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)"
I want to get variable like this , var day="Sun" var month="Aug" var year=2016;
How can I do that in pure js?

Comment: You might want to read up on the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Tried "var res = str.split(" ");'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can use destructuring if your code is running in an environment that supports that ES2015 feature or is being transpiled to ES5.

```
var str = "Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)";
var [day, month, , year] = str.split(' ');

console.log('day', day);
console.log('month', month);
console.log('year', year);
```

[Destructuring](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth)

Comment: Thanks.. Could you please explain the   ('day', day);

Comment: That's just how I label `console.log` statements. I just find its easier to keep track of what you're looking at when I do that. It's personal preference.

Actually, it probably makes more sense to just use one `console.log` to illustrate the concept like in Arnauld's response.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking how to split a date string into component pieces, you can make use of the date object:

```
var datestr = "Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0600";
var date = new Date(Date.parse(datestr));
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

See here for a list of functions available to the date object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

However, if you want a more general split of the string, you would want to use split, as mentioned above, or regex specifically to draw out the different components. Something like this:

```
/(\w+) (\w+) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4})/.exec(datestr);
```

Of course the problem with the above is that it presumes a very specific format, which may or may not be reliable in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use spli()

```
var my_string = "Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)";
var my_array = my:string.split( ' ' );

console.log(my_array[0]);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can do:

```
[ day, month,, year ] = str.split(' ');
```

Example:

```js
var str = "Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)",
    day, month, year;

[ day, month,, year ] = str.split(' ');

console.log('day = ' + day + ', month = ' + month + ', year = ' + year);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nice example!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you do with the values after

1. You could look into the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

   ```js
   var date = new Date('Sun Aug 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)');
   console.log('Day of the week:', date.getDay());
   console.log('Full year:', date.getFullYear());
   console.log('Month:', date.getMonth());
   ```

   after you can convert the numerical values if needed
2. Or simply parse the string date with a regular expression to extract the string values

Answer (score 0):

Make a Date object using that date string , then access all value by the properties .

```
var d = new Date(dateString);
    d.getDate() Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
    d.getDay()  Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
    d.getFullYear() Returns the year
    d.getHours()    Returns the hour (from 0-23)
    d.getMonth()    Returns the month (from 0-11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a date object from your date string:

```
var date = new Date(yourDateString);
```

Then you can use the `getDay()`, `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()` functions. These will return numbers i.e. `0-6` for day, `0-11` for month and just the year for year.

To get say the month as a string rather than a number you can set up an array:

```
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

var month = month[date.getMonth()];
```

To get the day as a string:

```
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var day = weekday[date.getDay()];
```

To the year:

```
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: FYI, getYear is deprecated. use getFullYear instead.

Comment: The problem is this string is generated from a jQurey calendar plugin.